# Implementing Test case

Tags: testcase

My question is about finding the best way to implement test cases to test both whole process and every class usage.

In our project, There are some dependent layers and every layer is responsible for something. In a specified process, Next layer uses the output of prior layer.

I'm not sure Which solution is better to implement test cases? If I write separated test cases for every class, then how to test functionality of whole the process? If I write a test for whole process, how can I manage it to know failures?

Is there any standard or methodology for it? Where is the best start point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***I'm not sure Which solution is better to implement test cases? If I write 
separated test cases for every class, then how to test functionality of whole the process?***

you should try to have a test case category. Category can be used to classify
your test cases. You can probably have a test case for unit test or use cases.

***If I write a test for whole process, how can I manage it to know failures?***

Part of [test case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case) have action and expected results, if the test output was
not the same as the expected results, then it is consider failure.

**Is there any standard or methodology for it? Where is the best start point?**

Start by learning from the existing test framework, you can use testopia for
example. If you need more information about a specific topic in software testing
in your cases, standard or methodology, you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSoftware_testing)